# Can a line of finite point charge configuration be in equilibrium?

Tags: charge, equilibrium

Can we arrange a finite number of point charges in a line so that they are all in equilibrium? Earnshaw's theorem proves that there cannot be a stable equilibrium point in an electric field, but what about unstable equilibrium? If not, how to prove it?

Comment: What about the hydrogen atom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I put a charge of $+4q$ at $x=+x_0$ and $x=-x_0$ and have charge of $-q$ at the origin then the force on the charge at the origin is 0 by symmetry and the force on the outer charges is $$\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{-4q^2}{x_0^2} + \frac{16q^2}{(2x_0)^2}\right) = 0$$ 
so the system is (unstable) equilibrium.

Comment: Ahh yes, good spot. thank you, I've corrected then numbers

Comment: You have not proven that the equilibrium is unstable.

Comment: @sammygerbil given that the OP mentioned Earnshaw's theorem and the fact that there are no stable equilibrium points in an EM field I felt that it was not necessary to prove it explicitly in this case.