# Finding equilibrium of a system by differentiating the potential energy of the system by one of the charge

Tags: electrostatics

> Four charges each equal to Q are placed at the four corners of a
> square and a charge q is placed at the centre of the square. If the
> system is in equilibrium, the value of q is:

I found the potential energy of this system as:

$$U = \frac{-4 \sqrt{2}kQq}{a} + \frac{4+2 \sqrt{2}kQ^2}{a}$$

And I'm visualizing a U-Q graph where as we change the Q, the potential energy reaches some minimum, implying that the system is stable. To find that:

$$ \frac{dU}{dQ} = \frac{-4 \sqrt{2}kq}{a} + 2(\frac{4+2 \sqrt{2}kQ}{a}) $$

And when equating this to 0, I get the answer as:

$$ q = (4 \sqrt{2} + 2)\frac{Q}{4} $$

And I'm successfully wrong, the actual answer when superposing forces gives out:

$$q = \frac{-Q}{4}(1+2 \sqrt{2}) $$

I'm off by a factor of 2 and a negative sign. Although the idea sits well in my head, but there must be something wrong. May I get to know what it is?

Comment: As you write $U$, the second term is dimensionally incorrect and also seems to have wrong factors in it... For the more fundamental aspects see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question and some similar ones are answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/803882/equilibrium-constellations-of-classical-point-charges-in-hollow-conductors/803883#803883). Note that your configuration can only attain *unstable* equilibrium. But that's still equilibrium of course.

You'll see that for different regular polygons you need:
$$  q_c=-q\ \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac1{4\sin(n\pi/N)} $$
$$    N=2 \ \   \Rightarrow \ \   q_c=-q/4 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$
$$   N=3 \ \   \Rightarrow \ \   q_c=-q/\sqrt3 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$
$$   N=4 \ \   \Rightarrow \ \   q_c=-q\ (2\sqrt2 + 1)/4  $$
$$   N=5 \ \   \Rightarrow \ \   q_c=-q \ \sqrt{1+2/\sqrt5} $$

What you do in your analysis is not testing for equilibrium against displacement of the charges, as that would require $d U/da$. You calculate in fact what would happen if the central charge $q$ is fixed and then charge is allowed to flow (in equal amounts) to the corner points. That is another equilibrium, and gives another value for $Q$, than the value for which the forces become $0$.